# Feature scaling (normalization) in multiple regression analysis with normal equation method?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, normalization, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am doing linear regression with multiple features. I decided to use normal equation method to find coefficients of linear model. If we use gradient descent for linear regression with multiple variables we typically do feature scaling in order to quicken gradient descent convergence. For now, I am going to use normal equation formula:

[image]

I have two contradictory information sources. In 1-st it is stated that no feature scaling required for normal equations. In another I can see that feature normalization has to be done.
Sources:

> http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/DocumentPage.php?course=MachineLearning&doc=exercises/ex3/ex3.html
>
> http://puriney.github.io/numb/2013/07/06/normal-equations-gradient-descent-and-linear-regression/

*At the end of these two articles information concerning feature scaling in normal equations presented.*

The question is do we need to do feature scaling before normal equation analysis?

Comment: Cross-posted on SO and Stats.SE: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/185624/2921, http://stackoverflow.com/q/34148912/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been posted on multiple Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may indeed not need to scale your features, and from theoretical point of view you get solution in just one "step". In practice, however, things might be a bit different.

Notice matrix inversion in your formula. Inverting a matrix is not quite trivial computational operation. In fact, there's a measure of how hard it's to invert a matrix (and perform some other computations), called [condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number#Matrices):

> If the condition number is not too much larger than one (but it can still be a multiple of one), the matrix is well conditioned which means its inverse can be computed with good accuracy. If the condition number is very large, then the matrix is said to be ill-conditioned. Practically, such a matrix is almost singular, and the computation of its inverse, or solution of a linear system of equations is prone to large numerical errors. A matrix that is not invertible has condition number equal to infinity.

P.S. Large condition number is actually the same problem that slows down gradient descent's convergence.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to perform feature scaling when using the normal equation. It's useful only for the gradient descent method to optimize the performance. The article from the Stanford University provides the correct information.

Of course you can scale the features in this case as well, but it will not bring you any advantages (and will cost you some additional calculations).